# How can I get return value from a stored procedure and use it in script task using OLE DB Command Task(Provider, Providerlocation) in SSIS?

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012, ssis-2012, oledbcommand

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZZfR.png)

How to get return value from OLE DB Command Task and use it in Script task?

Comment: Actually i have a flat file to insert using stored procedure i have to get return values for each and every row inserted. how can i get the return value in oledb command task?

Answer (score -1):

You can use  Execute SQL task to execute the stored procedure  and the returned value from the stored procedure then be set to a variable(i.e map the returned Result set to a variable). This variable can then be used by the script task.

Execute SQL task

[image]